# Can Latex formatting commands be used in Mendeley notes?

Tags: bibtex, annotations, mendeley

I am putting together an annotated bibliography and am using the "notes" field in Mendeley for my annotations. Mendeley automatically stores these notes in the bibtex annotate field. I am able to generate a bibliography that includes these annotations just fine.

I have noticed that if I create a bibtex file outside of Mendeley, I can format the annotation text using standard latex commands \textbf, \begin{center}\end{center} etc.

However, if I try to use latex typesetting from within the Mendeley notes field, Mendeley adds its own formatting to ensure my notes get printed verbatim.

i.e. literally "\textbf{Word I wanted bold}"

Is there any easy way around this?

Comment: Have you tried unticking "Escape Latex spacial characters" in the Mendeley preferences?

Comment: I didn't know that that option existed. Thank you!

Comment: No problem, hope this works.